# How to delete models using button and GET request in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

Here's the problem: in my rendered html-page I have multiple what I call 'thumbnails' of text data aka Notes (Note is my Model in Django). I decided it would be good idea to bind button "Delete" to every thumbnail: User clicks "Delete" on some Note —> it's get deleted.
What I've come to (in my views.py):

```
    ids=[x.id for x in Note.objects.all()]
    buttons = []
    for x in ids:
        buttons.append('DeleteButton' + str(x))
    if (request.GET.get(x for x in buttons)):
    print("Button click registered @ ", x)
```

Well, It doesn't actually register any button clicks and thus not printing "click registered". My button looks like this in notes.html:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value= "DeleteButton" name="DeleteButton{{ Note.id }}">
```

Any ideas how can I actually register any buttons clicked? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.GET.get(x for x in buttons)` doesn't do what you think at all. It tries to get a single parameter, consisting of a list of all the button names. That can never work.

But this is a very inefficient way of doing things anyway. Rather than iterating over every ID and seeing if it's in the GET, you should just find the things that *are* in the GET and extract their IDs. Something like:

```
button_ids = []
for item in request.GET:
    if item.startswith('DeleteButton'):
        button_ids.append(item.replace('DeleteButton', ''))
notes = Note.objects.filter(id__in=button_ids)
```

An even better way would be to use the actual `button` tag rather than `input`, which allows you to split the value from what is displayed in the button. Then you can just use a single `name` with different values.

```
<button name="DeleteButton" value="{{ note.id }}">
    Delete
</button>
```

Now you can simply do:

```
button_ids = request.GET.getlist('DeleteButton')
```

(Note that IE versions before 8 had various bugs with the button element, so if you need to support these this isn't a good idea.)

Comment: If I could upvote you 10000 times I definately would! Now whenever I click DeleteButton I receive 'GET' request with value of current button clicked! Works just perfect. Now I need to just write something like this:
if (request.GET.get('DeleteButton')):
Next question: after GET request I'm deleting object and rendering page again. But this GET request is still in my page address. How can I force reset page address after clicking DeleteButton?

  Note.objects.filter(id = request.GET.get('DeleteButton')).delete()

Comment: UPDT: Figured out.I just use
 if (request.GET.get('DeleteButton')):
  Note.objects.filter(id = request.GET.get('DeleteButton')).delete()
  return redirect('/notes/')